# How to add additional function to form submit button in Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, submit

I have a form and a submit button for it, how can I add additional functionality to this button, like for example I want to call sendNotification function when submit button is pressed. I googled and so far understand that this can be done by adding "onclick" javaScript function to that Submit button but then I need to call sendNotification in javaScript which seems to me kind of doing stuff around the corner, so I was wondering if there is some way to add function call to Submit button directly?

```
#updateProduct.html

<h1 style="font-size: 20px; margin-left: 10px;" class="p-2">
  Update Job
</h1>

<div class="container m-1">
   <form id=form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <input type="submit" name="Save Changes" class="btn btn-success m-0" value="Save Changes">
     <a class="btn btn-primary mt-0" href="{% url 'showProducts' %}" > Cancel </a>
   </form>

 <!--This button below separately works but can it be integreted to the submit button above-->
 <a href="{% url 'sendNotification' id email %}" class="btn btn-success" >Notify</a>
</div>
```

Below is the sendNotification function itself

```
#views.py

@login_required(login_url='sendNotification')
def sendNotification(request, pk, email):
  product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)

  msg = EmailMessage()
  msg.set_content(product.description + "  Here is the link for details: ZZZ+str(pk)+"/" )
  msg['subject'] = product.name
  msg['to'] = email

  user = "XX@gmail.com"
  msg['from'] = user
  password = "ZZZ"

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(user, password)
server.send_message(msg)

server.quit()

return redirect('showProducts')
```

Comment: If the sendNotification is on the back-end why not calling from the form's view?

Comment: good point :) I will try that, tnx

Comment: yeah that worked, thank you so much!